# Ubuntu 16.04 HWE & xserver-xorg-video-ast

Tags: 16.04, drivers, kernel, graphics, xorg

I have some troubles with installing the aspeed xorg module on my Ubuntu.

Basic System was the Ubuntu 16.04 LTE, with (working) ASpeed and (not working) GTX 1060.

To get my GTX 1060 running, I installed the HWE as described here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

This worked perfekt for the GTX 1060 (nice!) but, when I try to install the ASpeed modules I only get dependency errors:

```
# apt install xserver-xorg-video-ast
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-video-ast : Depends: xorg-video-abi-20
                      Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But when I check my installed packages i find these:

```
# dpkg --list | grep xserver-xorg-core
rc  xserver-xorg-core                                           2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.3                        amd64        Xorg X server - core server
ii  xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04                                 2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1~16.04.2                  amd64        Xorg X server - core server
```

When I try to install the xorg-video-abi-20, apt wants to uninstall most of Ubuntu (like ubuntu-desktop) and give me this note:

```
Note, selecting 'xserver-xorg-core' instead of 'xorg-video-abi-20'
```

So, was the package xserver-xorg-video-ast(-hwe-16.04) just forgotten to be ported, or am I missing a part to get it working again?

Comment: You are correct. There is no `xserver-xorg-video-ast-hwe-16.04`. Report it as a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Reported a bug. (Even so reporting a bug is unnecessary  complicated!)